# Displaying emojionearea emoji container at the bottom of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, emojione

I just applied emojionearea.js to my textarea but emoji are been displayed at the top of my textarea, hiding its view from users.

[image]

I will like to know how to position its container to the bottom of my textarea.

my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".emoji_act").emojioneArea({
    emojiPlaceholder: ":smile_cat:",
    searchPlaceholder: "Search",
    buttonTitle: "Use your TAB key to insert emoji faster",
    searchPosition: "bottom",
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid pt-3">
  <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
      <font color="#a1a1a1"><span id="count"></span> characters remaining</font>
      <textarea type="text" name="bio" class="form-control emoji_act" id="bio" placeholder="10 - 140 characters" onkeyup="count_char(this, 140)"></textarea>
      <span id="bio_val"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button id="ok_but" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="ed_submit">
          Done
         </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you please put your code snippet in question ? (html+css+js)

Comment: Sorry for that. Check now @ArashKhajelou

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to learn how to use this js lib, please follow [this document](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea).

now lets solve your current problem:

you can set the property `pickerPosition` to `bottom` in your initial config which is passed to `emojioneArea` jquery function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".emoji_act").emojioneArea({
    emojiPlaceholder: ":smile_cat:",
    searchPlaceholder: "Search",
    buttonTitle: "Use your TAB key to insert emoji faster",
    searchPosition: "bottom",
    pickerPosition: "bottom"
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid pt-3">
  <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
      <font color="#a1a1a1"><span id="count"></span> characters remaining</font>
      <textarea type="text" name="bio" class="form-control emoji_act" id="bio" placeholder="10 - 140 characters" onkeyup="count_char(this, 140)"></textarea>
      <span id="bio_val"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button id="ok_but" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="ed_submit">
          Done
         </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.js"></script>
```